# IrfanView Is there a way to search for images whose titles *don't* contain a certain string?

Tags: search, irfanview

In Irfanview>Options>Search Files.. dialog box, is there a way to search for images which **don't** have a certain word in the file name?

I wish to search for ones which don't have 'balloon' in their name. I've tried adding a negative symbol (-) before the search word, but no luck.

Comment: If the title is in the image, I think you would need to convert the image to searchable using OCR.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Irfanview is not the best tool for searching file-names. I could recommend [voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/) which has a NOT operator.

Comment: IrfanView *does* have useful search features, such as looking in Comments, EXIF and IPTC data. However, for searching by filename, use the Windows Explorer or other file manager's native search features, e.g., `NOT port`, which eliminates filenames with "portrait" and "Portugal".

Comment: @ john "filename"
@ harrymc @DrMoishe Pippik I'm able to perform the filter in other programs such as Windows File Explorer, but the 'Show in Thumbnails' is the reason I wish to do it within IrfanView. Is there another program which could perform similar to this feature? I don't need to edit the images, just view & catalogue them.

Comment: To show thumbnails in Windows Explorer *Search* results, press Ctrl-Shift-1 for large images, Ctrl-Shift-2 for medium, and Ctrl-Shift-3 for small. Change at any time, even in the middle of a search. (-6 gets Details view)